# How to use the data imported from excel in R?

Tags: r

I import the data from excel in the following way.

```r
h <- read_excel("... ExcelFiles/h.xlsx", 
                               col_names = FALSE)
```

In the Global environment, it reads as

```r
50 obs. of 36 variable.
```

When I use this h in other functions, I get the error s

```r
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"
```

and

```r
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

On the other hand, If I generate h in R in the following way,

```r
h <- runif(50 * 36) %>% matrix(nrow = 50)
```

I get no error!

Then how I can use the h that I export from excel in R?

Comment: Your first `h` is a `data.frame`, your second `h` is a `matrix`. They are not the same.

Comment: @r2evans, how to convert this data.frame into matrix?

Comment: Have you tried `as.matrix(h)`?

Comment: @r2evans, thanks as.matrix dis not work. h <- apply(as.matrix.noquote(dframe),  2,as.numeric) worked!